# Where are the fuel tanks located in an Antonov An-225?

Tags: fuel-tanks, antonov-225

Does anyone have answer for where the fuel tanks are located on the Antonov An-225?
(photo attached for explanation if anyone could)
Would love to know how many tanks are on the aircraft and how the system works.

*Please let me know if I've colored right sections on the wings indicating the fuel tanks positions.. if not, let me know which ones to modify.

Really appreciate your help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The 225 is derived from the An-124, which has [10 integral fuel tanks](http://www.aircraftinformation.info/art_An-124.htm) in the wings. Comparing the specs, it looks like fuel capacity is the same as the An-124, so the center section of the wing (the only new part of the wing) doesn't contain fuel.

Based on that, I think the tanks are in sections 2-6 and 13-17. I'm assuming the outer wing sections 1 and 18 are not used as tanks. If those were used as tanks you'd have higher loads on the wing during roll maneuvers.

Comment: The tanks near the wingtips might be Surge tanks and not normal fuel tanks. They're found on many transport category aircraft, they're there to provide space for fuel flow during refuelling in case of overfilling and for fuel to collect during the violent manoeuvres

Comment: One would hope that _transport_ category aircraft don't experience too many "violent maneuvers", @AmanVishwakarma!

Comment: Haha I know, there are baffle check valves incorporated, but you can never be too safe, right? It's just a fail safe design feature